# How to set proxy in Glide library

Tags: android, proxy, android-glide

I'm using Psiphon vpn bundled in my app, so all REST calls goes through a local port.

I've added a proxy to `OkHttp` client in`Retrofit` like this:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder client = 
            new OkHttpClient.Builder().proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
            new InetSocketAddress("localhost", randomPort )));
builder.client(client.build());
retrofit = builder.build();
```

Everything works fine so far and I can load all text contents through local proxy successfully, but images didn't load because Glide has a custom connection.

Now I want to set a proxy similar to above code to Glide, or any other libraries for image loading

I'm using Glide "4.8.0" simply like this:

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(image_url)
            .into(miniImageView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using custom `@GlideModule`

Add following lines into app `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation('com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.8.0') {
   exclude group: 'glide-parent'
}
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

And here is my custom module:

```
@GlideModule
public class CustomGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

  @Override
  public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
    Builder builder = new Builder()
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if (VpnService.connected) {
      builder.proxy(VpnService.proxy);
    }
    OkHttpClient client = builder.build();

    OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory factory = new OkHttpUrlLoader.Factory(client);

    glide.getRegistry().replace(GlideUrl.class, InputStream.class, factory);
  }
}
```

Glide will detect it automatically using `@GlideModule` on top of the class and will inject it on runtime. Now every image loading of Glide will go through my custom module and custom OkHttp connection